# Can you replicate the functionality of an Access "Continuous Form"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My task is to "convert" an Access database to C# for Intranet use, so I guess I should say this is C#/ASP or however it's commonly referred to.

One of my forms is a continuous form.  In Access, a continuous form lets you place controls once on your form, and those controls get repeated for every record in your dataset.  This allows you to have, say, a checkbox control linked to a Yes/No field, and that checkbox will appear for every record you display on the form.

I don't even know if this can be done, but probably 90% of what I've written so far came from suggestions/samples I found on this site so I figure this is the place to ask.

So, is there an equivalent of a Continuous Form in C#?

Comment: I personally don't know what a continious form is - it might be worth explaining what it is/how it works so people without access knowledge can help?

Comment: Here is a good definition: "Microsoft Access continuous form is a special type of form , when an entire form design is repeated for each record of the data source. It gives you ability to make something different than the usual “table-view” approach"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use the [Repeater control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/x8f2zez5%28v%3dvs.100%29).  I would look at getting your data from the Entity Framework.

> The Repeater Web server control is a data-bound container control that
> produces a list of individual items. You define the layout of
> individual items on a Web page using templates. When the page is run,
> the control repeats the layout for each item in the data source. You
> must complete several steps to add a Repeater Web server control to a
> Web forms page. The following procedure describes the minimum that you
> must do to create a working Repeater control.